# How can I make this button's border style using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make a button's border look like the image below using CSS? Here's what I've tried - https://jsfiddle.net/rx9sLtjp/10/

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

```css
body{
  background: #070707;
}
.button-style {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;

  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;

  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #070707 linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(117, 42, 135, 0.5) 0%, rgba(36, 18, 124, 0.5) 100%);

  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: -1px;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #b415a2 0%, #3116ac 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="header__registration button-style">registration</button>
```

Comment: looks good.  What's the problem?

Comment: @DCR side cutouts

Comment: Here is a tool that might be helpful for you - https://css-generators.com/custom-borders/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea combining clip-path and mask:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  position: relative;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% calc(50% - 18px),calc(100% - 18px) 50%,100% calc(50% + 18px),100% 100%,0 100%,0 calc(50% + 18px),18px 50%,0 calc(50% - 18px));
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #b415a2, #3116ac);
  -webkit-mask:
    conic-gradient(from   45deg at calc(100% - 20px) 50%,#000 90deg,#0000 0) content-box,
    conic-gradient(from -135deg at 20px 50%,#000 90deg,#0000 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: add,add,exclude;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> some text </div>
```

Comment: I will update later with CSS variable to make it easy to control